# Validation with jq validate

Tags: jquery, jquery-validate

I'm trying to execute this, but i can't understand why it doesn't do nothing!

I think the problem is at the button.

PD: Thank you very much for your cooperation in advance.

EDIT: This is the complete code.

```
<?php
require_once("scr/insert.php");
?>

<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title></title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/estilo.css" type="text/css"/>
    <!--[if lt IE 9]>
    <script src="http://html5shim.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/html5.js"></script>
    <![endif]-->
</head>
<body>

    <div class="container">
        <div class="side">
            <div class="logo"></div>
            <div class="tvimagen">
                <h1>sign up with your
                beauty salon 
                <strong>and win a 42" tv</strong></h1>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="formulario">
            <form action="scr/insert.php" id="formform" method="post">
                <label for="salon">Beauty Salon Name:</label>
                <input type="text" name="salon" />

                <label for="owner">Owner:</label>
                <input type="text" name="owner" />

                <label for="owner_bdate">Owner's date of birth: <em>(optional)</em></label>
                <input type="text" name="owner_bdate" />

                <label for="address">Address:</label>
                <input type="text" name="address" />

                <label for="zip">Zip Code:</label>
                <input type="text" name="zip" />

                <label for="seats">Number of Seats:</label>
                <input type="text" name="seats" />

                <label for="phone">Phone:</label>
                <input type="text" name="phone" />

                <label for="email">Email:</label>
                <input type="text" name="email" />

                <label for="seller">Seller Name:</label>
                <input type="text" name="seller" />

                <label for="website">Website:</label>
                <input type="text" name="website" />

                <span>
                    <input type="checkbox" name="terms" value="1" />
                    <p>I accept the Terms and Conditions</p>
                </span>
                <!-- <a href="javascript:;" class="enviarbt" onclick="validate()">register</a> -->
                <input type="submit"  class="enviarbt" value="Register" onclick="jodete()" id="boton">
            </form>
        </div>
    </div>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery-1.11.0.min.js"></script>
    <!-- <script type="text/javascript" src="js/jqfunc-1.0.0.js"></script> -->
    <script type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery.validate.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript">

            $(function(){
            $("#formform").validate({

                rules :{

                    salon: {required: true, minlength: 5},
                    owner: {required: true, minlength: 4, maxlength: 20},
                    //owner_bdate: {required: true},
                    address: {required: true, minlength: 15},
                    zip: {required: true, number: true},
                    seats: {required: true, number: true},
                    phone: {required: true, number: true},
                    email: {required: true, email: true},
                    seller: {required: true, minlength: 4, maxlength 20},
                    website: {url: true}
                        }
            });
        });
    </script> 


</body>
</html>
```

Comment: What button?  You haven't shown enough HTML for the form.

Comment: FYI, there is no such thing as a `</input>` tag.  "Void" (empty) elements such as `<input>` do not have closing tags.  But I doubt this is the cause of your problem.

Comment: Regarding your selector: `$("#formform")`.  Are you sure your `form` element contains `id="formform"`?  Are you getting any JavaScript errors?  Have you done any troubleshooting?

Comment: Yes, it has formform as id.

Comment: I already edited it and added the complete code, check it again, please...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I guess you didn't notice the JavaScript errors in your console.

You have a syntax error...

```
seller: {required: true, minlength: 4, maxlength 20}
```

should be...

```
seller: {required: true, minlength: 4, maxlength: 20}
```

(You were missing the colon, `:`, after `maxlength`)

DEMO:  http://jsfiddle.net/9z4G6/

---

BTW, you can also combine the `minlength` and `maxlength` rules into the `rangelength` rule...

```
rangelength:  [4,20]
```

http://jsfiddle.net/9z4G6/1/